# optimizing recursion in xsl template

Tags: xslt, recursion, graph

I need to solve this classical graph problem... in xsl : i need to compute the list of all nodes which belong to all paths from given source nodes to sink nodes (with eventually cycles). Here is an example xml file representing such a graph (with a (D,C) cycle)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<graph>
    <node id="A" source="yes">
        <child node="D"/>
        <child node="G"/>
    </node>
    <node id="B">
        <child node="E"/>
        <child node="F"/>
    </node>
    <node id="C">
        <child node="D"/>
        <child node="E"/>
        <child node="F"/>
    </node>
    <node id="D">
        <child node="C"/>
        <child node="E"/>
        <child node="F"/>
    </node>
    <node id="E"/>
    <node id="F"/>
    <node id="G"/>
</graph>
```

Here is a stylesheet I have written, which uses a recursive template with two parameters storing a list of already visited nodes and a list of nodes to be visited :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"  exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">

  <xsl:output  method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="nodes" match="node" use="@id"/> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="graph">
        <graph>
            <xsl:call-template name="search-alt">
                <xsl:with-param name="todo">
                    <xsl:for-each select="node[@source='yes']">
                        <link node="{@id}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </graph>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="search-alt">
        <xsl:param name="todo"/>
        <xsl:param name="visited"/>
        <xsl:variable name="nodeid" select="exslt:node-set($todo)/*[1]/@node"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="exslt:node-set($visited)/*[@node=$nodeid]">
                <xsl:if test="exslt:node-set($todo)/*[position()&gt;1]">
                    <xsl:call-template name="search-alt">
                        <xsl:with-param name="todo">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="exslt:node-set($todo)/*[position()&gt;1]"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="visited">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$visited"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(key('nodes',$nodeid)/child) or (exslt:node-set($todo)/*[position()&gt;1])">
                <node id="{$nodeid}"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="search-alt">
                    <xsl:with-param name="todo">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="key('nodes',$nodeid)/child"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="exslt:node-set($todo)/*[position()&gt;1]"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="visited">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$visited"/>
                        <link node="{$nodeid}"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the above graph the stylesheet outputs what I expect (a disconnected graph composed of visited nodes), i.e. the B node is not visited :

```
<graph>
    <node id="A"/>
    <node id="D"/>
    <node id="C"/>
    <node id="E"/>
    <node id="F"/>
</graph>
```

I have tested this template on a bigger graph (two thousand nodes) but weakly connected (nodes have less that 7 children) and my xslt processor does only take 2 seconds to do the job.

Since I will need to work with bigger graphs my question is : is it possible to decrease the level of recursion, which here is equal to the length of the longest path ? The bigger problem is that the two lists have to be passed as parameters and are monotonically growing.

Thanks for your hints !

S.

Comment: Two questions: (a) are you really constrained to use XSLT 1.0 for this? (b) do you know whether the processor you are using optimizes tail calls? (If it does, then there's very little point trying to reduce the depth of recursion.)

Comment: (a) I use xsltproc (gnome project), which still does not support XSLT 2.0. (b) I don't know

Comment: Then before rewriting your code I would do some experiments to determine the answer to (b), e.g. write something that does tail-recursion over a sequence of 10000 nodes. If it can't handle the recursion, then I would be seriously inclined to change technology. Writing this kind of thing in XSLT 1.0 is seriously difficult because templates can't return references to nodes, they can only return copies of nodes.

Comment: I have tested the template on a random graph (2000 nodes, with a maximum number of 6 children, uniformly drawn) and xsltproc fails (message is :xsltApplyXSLTTemplate: A potential infinite template recursion was detected.You can adjust xsltMaxDepth (--maxdepth) in order to raise the maximum number of nested template calls and variables/params (currently set to 3000)).

Comment: Doesn't surprise me greatly; there's been no development on xsltproc for a long time. Do you really have to use it?

Comment: I have tested Saxon 6.5.5, which correctly does the job for a graph of 10000 nodes !